# JSON.net SelectToken() with single quote in path

Tags: json, json.net

Consider this json:

```
{
    "farms": [
        {
            "fred's": {
                "cows": 5,
                "pigs": 2,
                "horses": "none"
            }
        }, {
            "old mcdonald's": {
                "cows": none,
                "pigs": 1,
                "horses": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There seems to be no problem with using single quotes alone:

```
JObject j = new JObject();
JToken jt = j.SelectToken(farms.fred's);
```

However, errors occur when trying to use both single quotes and white spaces.

Using this code:

```
JObject j = new JObject();
JToken jt = j.SelectToken(farms.old mcdonald's);
```

I got this error:

> JsonException: Unexpected character while parsing path

So I did some searching and found that terms with white spaces must be surrounded by:

```
[' ']
```

Example:

```
JObject j = new JObject();
JToken jt = j.SelectToken(farms.['old mcdonald's']);
```

However, now the error is:

> JsonException: Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: s

Is it possible to include both white spaces and single quotes in the SelectToken path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems so...

```
var x = @"{
    ""farms"": [
        {
            ""fred's"": {
                ""cows"": 5,
                ""pigs"": 2,
                ""horses"": ""none""
            }
        },
        {
            ""old mcdonald's"": {
                ""cows"": ""none"",
                ""pigs"": 1,
                ""horses"": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}";

var j = JObject.Parse(x);
var jobj = j.SelectToken("farms[1]['old mcdonald\\'s']") as JObject;
jobj.Properties().Select( p => p.Name + ": " + p.Value).Dump();
```

---

```
IEnumerable<String> (3 items)
* cows: none 
* pigs: 1 
* horses: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I am still getting an error. While there is no longer an error on SelectToken, SelectToken now returns null.

Comment: @fractal Download LINQPad, https://www.linqpad.net, copy/paste the code answer, set **Language**:`C# Statements(s)` and run it. It should work. I suspect `null` is an indication that there's a problem with the code *in your program*. Maybe missing `farms[1]`.

Comment: You are correct. It was a problem with code in my program. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @fractal don't forget to mark solution as answer. :)